# Automated image comparisons

Tags: php

I am comparing versions of EmojiOne emoji images.

I have each EmojiOne emoji stored in a MySQL table, and I know the emojione version it was first released at.

I have another table of EmojiOne releases.

I have a php script which loops through the releases, and then displays the image for each release for each emoji in a grid. There is a checkbox against each image, holding the version number and emoji ID split by a pipe.

For each emoji, I do this:

1. Tab through the images - mark the first image, as that's the first release version
2. Tick any images which have a different design to the previous image
3. Submit the form
4. The form works through the submitted data and loads the results into a version matrix table, holding the emoji ID and the version ID - e.g.

   ```
      int  emoji_id  version_id  entered              
   ------  --------  ----------  ---------------------
     2257         1           1  2018-05-17 18:27:09  
     2258         1          19  2018-05-17 18:27:09  
     2259         1          22  2018-05-17 18:27:09  
     2260         1          29  2018-05-17 18:27:09  
     2261         1          37  2018-05-17 18:27:09  
     2262         2           1  2018-05-17 18:28:01  
     2263         2          19  2018-05-17 18:28:01  
     2264         2          22  2018-05-17 18:28:01  
     2265         2          24  2018-05-17 18:28:01  
     2266         2          29  2018-05-17 18:28:01  
     2267         2          37  2018-05-17 18:28:01  
     2268         3           1  2018-05-17 18:28:27  
     2269         3          19  2018-05-17 18:28:27  
     2270         3          22  2018-05-17 18:28:27  
     2271         3          29  2018-05-17 18:28:27  
     2272         3          37  2018-05-17 18:28:28  
     2273         3          41  2018-05-17 18:28:28
   ```

The tool I made looks like this for a given set of emojis to check:

[image]

It's fairly prone to human error as well.

There are 2,666 images I need to do this for - so it's a very time consuming process as I can get through at most about 100 emojis in an evening after work and other commitments, so it will take about 2 weeks to compare the full load of images.

For example, for the 1F602 emoji, the SVG versions differ as follows (once you ignore all the versions where the images are the same):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

And the PNG differ as follows:

[image]
[image]

I wondered if there would be any way to automate this using an image comparison solution?

All of the images are held remotely on CDNs (cloudflare for the SVG images, jsdelivr for the PNG images) - e.g.

1. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/1.0.0/assets/svg/1F602.svg
2. https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.0/png/128/1f602.png

I realise I'm probably asking for "the moon on a stick" and that this is a very vague query.

Comment: I don't understand why would you need an image comparison. When you get your emojis from the CDNs, you know them per version and per name. Can't you uses theses information?

Comment: You could probably look for some sort of neural network library, feeding all existing data (Image file => emoji ID) to the network as learning data and then continue feeding new images to it, fixing errors it produces and getting better results with every new data load.

Answer (score -1):

You must use a hash function to compare your images, regardless of the type.

Here is an example of a function using sha1 to compare 2 images:

```
function compare_distant_image($url_image1, $url_image1) {
// return true if the images are the same

    $content1 = file_get_contents($url_image1);
    $content2 = file_get_contents($url_image2);

    $hash1 = sha1($content1);
    $hash2 = sha1($content2);

    return $hash1 == $hash2;
}
```

Comment: On my understanding; your solution wont work since emojis are not the same one version to another.

Comment: This function will allow him to know if he is dealing with the same image.

Comment: let's pretend the emojicons will be visually exactly the same; the file contents will differ. Svg images are totally different from png images. Png images are totally different from jpg. Comparing the file hash will _always_ give you a different result. Only two pngs could be compared like that, or two jpgs